# Python 3 requests.get().text returns unencoded string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Python 3 requests.get().text returns unencoded string.
If I execute:

```
import requests
request = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=Кто является президентом России?').text.lower()
print(request)
```

I get kind of this:

```
&#1050;&#1090;&#1086; &#1103;&#1074;&#1083;&#1103;&#1077;&#1090;&#1089;&#1103; &#1087;&#1088;&#1077;&#1079;&#1080;&#1076;
```

I've tried to change `google.com` to `google.ru`

If I execute:

```
import requests
request = requests.get('https://google.ru/search?q=Кто является президентом России?').text.lower()
print(request)
```

I get kind of this:

```
d0%9a%d1%82%d0%be+%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f+%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc+%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0
```

I need to get an encoded normal string.

Answer (score 1):

You were getting this error because requests was not able to identify the correct encoding of the response. So if you are sure about the response encoding then you can set it like the following:

`response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding  --> to check the encoding
response.encoding = "utf-8" --> or any other encoding.`

And then get the content with .text method.

Comment: Here was a man who gave me the same advice. But that didn't work.

Comment: unquote method is also encoding to utf-8 only. the only additional thing it is doing is escaping the `%xx` character. But if read your question it says the complete response content is coming as unencoded.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with `urllib.parse.unquote()` method:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote

request = unquote(requests.get('https://google.ru/search?q=Кто является президентом России?').text.lower())
print(request)
```